# Google+ Hangouts window steals focus [when switching desktops]

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-hangouts

When I switch to a desktop that has the hangouts "window" on it, it steals the focus.

Steps to repeat:
* Desktop 1 has a terminal and the hangouts window
* Type in the terminal
* Switch to desktop 2 (using CTRL+ALT+RightArrow)
* Switch back to desktop 1
* Continue typing in the terminal

Outcome:
Nothing happens in the terminal because your focus is on hangouts (as visible in the desktop title bar)

Expected:
The terminal keeps focus

This is just one example (switching desktops) but there seems to be lots of different ways in which hangouts steals focus.

It's not a traditional window so I don't see options to disable "always on top" if that's what's happening.

This is the hangouts "window" I'm referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'Always on top' behavior can be toggled in the settings for the hangouts app itself.  Click on the gear icon to get to the settings menu.

[image: hangouts settings]

Comment: I can't seem to find settings that look like your screenshot. Is this for the [Hangouts Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en) or am I using something different?

Comment: Ah yup, looks like I was using the older Hangouts app, which suffers from the same issue, but hides its settings in a different place.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because Hangouts is set to "Always on Top".

Unfortunately, this "window" is stripped down and has no title bar to right click on, nor does it have options in the menu bar.  So we need to revert to the command-line and `wmctrl`.  Open a terminal and enter:

```
wmctrl -r Hangouts -b remove,above
```

Another option is to use the "Alt + Space" keyboard shortcut which will show the window menu.

Answer (score 1):

This did also hit me. It looks like it steels the focus when it moves with your view to the active desktop. I disabled it and the problem is gone:

[image: Hangouts App options page]

This options page is hidden behind the menu button (three stripes) next to your name.